# How to normalize mysql database table

Tags: mysql, normalization

For a mysql database I have two similar tables:

1.st table
**track_tag** (2 million rows)

id (int), track_id (int), tag (varchar)

2.nd table
**tag** (150.000 rows)

id (int), tag(varchar)

I want to normalize first table tag column with the second table's primary key.
What is the fastest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does each `track_id` correspond to a unique `tag` ?  If so, then just remove the `tag` column from `track_tag`.

Comment: Fastest way in terms of what? Design? Two seconds. Actually implementing and moving data? Longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're *not* working on a production DB (and hence things like long-running queries, and dropping/re-creating tables are OK) - then I think the **fastest** way would be to use a [Create Table AS SELECT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE track_tag_V2 AS SELECT track.id AS id, track.track_id, tag.id AS tag_id
FROM track_tag track, tag
WHERE track.tag = tag.tag
;
```

And then (Assuming the structure is to your liking) simply `DROP track_tag` and then `RENAME track_tag_V2 to track_tag` and you're done!

However, this *may not* (and **probably** *will* not) the the ***BEST*** way.  If your DB is de-normalised to this point, it may have been done for performance reasons already (normalisation optimises storage, not performance).  It may also be in need of a total re-design (which is *not* fast).

Answer (score 0):

Your tag table is fine with columns as : id (int), tag(varchar)

Note: Assuming id field is here primary key other wise create index on it.

But change track_tag table as per below-

id (int), track_id (int), tag_id (int)

Note: tag_id field should be indexed here.

Also not clear what is track_id field here.